# Creating a Progress Bar for HTTP GET Request? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-httpclient

So, I have an HTTP client get request  in Angular to get certain specific data from the server endpoint (which is in Python and uses the falcon framework). I need to see the upload progress of the data on a progress bar depending on the data size. Is there a way this could be possible?

Comment: This might help you: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-image-upload-with-progress-bar-exampleexample.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to [upload the file in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11827276/3022387) and there's [a very good module ready to use by blueimp](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).
But that's all pure JavaScript, not angular centric.